# Java: How to implement a portlistener that doesn't block the rest of the program

Tags: java, multithreading, listener

I have `Main` class in which I define the Java FX scene and stage, and a `MainController` in which I create a database connection and start up a `PortListener`. The 3 different parts (`Views`, `DB connection` and Port Listener`) all function when tested separately, but when I uncomment the parts so I can test the program in full working, it doesn't work.

```
public class Main extends Application {
MainController mainController;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1100, 690);

    root.setTop(setupMenuBar());
    root.setCenter(setupCenter());
    root.setBottom(setupStatusBar());

    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    mainController = new MainController();
    mainController.initController(primaryStage);

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

The problem is that I never get to `primaryStage.show();` of the main program because the `portlistener` just sits and waits for incoming messages so it seems to me there's only one thread running. (I thought java was multi-threaded by default)

The `portlistener` should wait for incoming messages, but it shouldn't block the `Main` program from functioning. I've changed the `Portlistener` to implement `Runnable`, but I read somewhere that a runnable's `run()` method should be called from a newly created thread's `start()` method in another class.

Now there's a problem, I've created a `startListening` function in the `portListener` that has 2 parameters, the `portNumber` to listen to, and the `mainController` instance, so the `portlistener` can call a function in the `MainController` once there is an incoming message. The `MainController` has the database connection and the variables like the port number, effectively being the class where everything comes together.

The `PortListener`:

```
public class PortListener implements Runnable {
    boolean stayConnected = true;
    MainController mainController;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket clientSocket = null;

    public void startListening(int portNumber, MainController controller) throws IOException {
        mainController = controller;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not start listener on port: " + portNumber);
            return;
        }

        while(stayConnected) {
            run();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection established");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                // TODO: handle incoming message by calling mainController
                System.out.println("Line incoming: " + inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            clientSocket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Portlistener run() failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void stopListening() {
        stayConnected = false;
    }
}
```

I'm probably just missing something trivial, but as there are so many skilled programmers here, I'd rather ask what I'm missing instead of trying another hour (or two).

Comment: Yes, you must use either `new Thread(myRunnable).start()` or submit the runnable to an Executor Service.

Comment: `I thought java was multithreaded by default`: It is, in the background... It won' t do your job by default though...

Comment: @Marko: But how do you pass a parameter then?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking, but most typically you pass all the data to the `myRunnable` constructor.

Comment: That was what I needed, gee, must be Monday that I didn't remember such a basic thing ... Thanx!